# how to pass a reference to a component when calling a vuex action

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm fairly new to vue (and very new to vuex). I would like to move some axios api calls to be actions in my Vuex store. I know have for example:

```
  actions:{
    LOAD_USER: function ({ commit }) {
      axios.get('/arc/api/v1/me', {dataType: 'json'})
      .then((response )=> {
        commit('SET_USER', { user: response.data.user })
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      });
```

and call this in my calling component via:

```
  this.$store.dispatch('LOAD_USER')
```

and this is working. My problem is that I need to set some variables in the calling component to false or kill a progress bar. Here's what I was previously using in my calling component:

```
  this.loading = true
  this.$Progress.start()
  axios.get('/arc/api/v1/me', {dataType: 'json'})
  .then((response )=> {
    this.$Progress.finish()
    this.loading = false
    this.$store.state.user = response.data.user;
    this.user = this.$store.state.user
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    this.$Progress.fail()
    console.log(error.message);
  });
```

How would I integrate these loading behaviors into my vuex action? How would I pass a reference to my component via this call:

```
  this.$store.dispatch('LOAD_USER')
```

or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can always use the second parameter of [**Store.dispatch()**](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/api.html#vuexstore-instance-methods) to pass any payload into the corresponding action:

```
this.$store.dispatch('LOAD_USER', this); // passing reference as payload
```

... but I strongly recommend against doing this. Instead, I'd rather have the whole state (including 'loading' flag, etc.) processed by VueX.

In this case, a single [**action**](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html) - **LOAD_USER**, based on asynchronous API request - would commit two [**mutations**](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html) to Store: the first one sets `loading` flag when the request has been started, the second one resets it back to `false` - and loads the user data. For example:

```
LOAD_USER: function ({ commit }) {
  commit('LOADING_STARTED'); // sets loading to true
  axios.get('/arc/api/v1/me', {dataType: 'json'})
  .then(response => {
    commit('LOADING_COMPLETE'); // resets loading flag
    commit('SET_USER', { user: response.data.user });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    commit('LOADING_ERROR', { error }); // resets loading
    console.log(error.message);
  });
```

This approach, among the other advantages, simplifies things a lot when your requests' logic gets more complicated - with error handling, retries etc.

Comment: I agree in principle that it's really ugly to pass the component via the action. But would the LOADING_STARTED / LOADING_COMPLETE be mutating some underlying `is_loading` attribute in vuex that I now need to watch in my components? Or would I bring that UI piece functionality into vuex (and how would I be able to do that?).  Sorry for questions - I just discovered EventBus a couple of days ago and feel if I can get a handle on Vuex, I'll feel more confident.

Comment: No, vuex should manage the state, and vue components should represent it (changing when the state changes, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Actions can return a promise https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html
I think what you want to do is activate the loading when you call your action and stop the loading when the promise is resolved or rejected.

```
// Action which returns a promise.
actions: {
  LOAD_USER ({ commit }) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios.get('/arc/api/v1/me', {dataType: 'json'})
        .then((response )=> {
          commit('SET_USER', { user: response.data.user })
          resolve()
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error.message);
          reject(error);
        });
    })
  }
}

// Update loading when the action is resolved.
this.loading = true;
store.dispatch('LOAD_USER').then(() => {
  this.loading = false;
})
.catch(function(error) {
  // When the promise is rejected
  console.log(error);
  this.loading = false;
});
```

If you can't achieve your goal using the above you can add the loading boolean to your vuex store and import it in your component. Than modify the loading boolean inside your action (using mutations) to let the view update.

Note: I would not pass a reference to your actions. While this is possible there are likely better solutions to solve your problem. try to keep the view logic in your components whenever possible.

Comment: hmm... so this is also interesting. Is there a way in the returned Promise to catch the error? And run some error code in that situation?

Comment: @timpone You can add catch for this, I've updated the code above.